# Backup website using SSH through terminal?

Tags: ssh

I just completed a magento website online, but I don't have any of the files on my local hard drive (couldn't install it on MAMP).  But I would like to make a back up.

My hosting company lets me connect to the server through SSH on my mac terminal.

**My question is, what is the line of command to copy from server to local drive?**

With a sample path and/or example would be nice...and I'm also guessing it is a **good idea to tar it before hand, how do I do that?**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Linux locally, you can use `scp` (secure copy) to transfer files from:

- remote to local
- local to remote
- remote to remote

Syntax for remote to local:

`scp username@server:/remote/path/to/file /path/to/local/dir`

If you're transferring many files, it's probably a good idea to tar the files. Here's a reference on the tar syntax and options you may want:

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utar.htm

Answer (score 2):

You should use rsync over ssh to make the backup:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh remotehost:/path/to/site /local/backup/directory/
```

It's restartable and only transfers what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save a tar file on your mac, here is another option.

```
ssh user@server '( cd /remote/path/ && tar cfz - . )' > site_backup.tar.gz
```

This option uses no extra disk space on the remote machine.  It creates the tar file and immediately pushes it out over the ssh connection and saves it on your Mac.

Comment: I get this error in the terminal, do you know what it means?  or what I need to do?  "tar: Old option `f' requires an argument"

Comment: hmm, try this:   ssh user@server '( cd /remote/path && tar cf - . | gzip -9 )' > site_backup.tar.gz

Comment: `f` should be last: `tar czf`

Answer (score -1):

You can use WinSCP as a windows client if you need to transfer files from a remote server to a local windows machine via SSH.